# Horizontal controlgroup nested in a listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I'm trying to implement jQuery radio buttons in horizontal `controlgroup` nested in a `listview`. Desired radio buttons are included in `<p class="ui-li-aside">` tag, which expected to display on right side of the list, but it's currently below the text.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h5gcL/)

How to display horizontal radio buttons on the right side of the app.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding your elements to gridview. Makes it cleaner to use and simpler to maintain. In your `li`,

Then, adding the grid in a `li` makes it lose its styling -  so add this css snip as well along with `text-align: right` on the second block ie., `ui-block-b` element (you need this to make the controlgroup end up in the right hand)

```
.ui-block-b {
    text-align:right;
}
ul > li
{
    height: 80px;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/h5gcL/11/

Answer (score 0):

So this is CSS question then. You should wrap the text in one `<div>` and float both that `<div>` and the `<p class="ui-li-aside">` below.

Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/h5gcL/6/

Hope it helps ;)